# Searching for sequence of bits in an integer in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, binding, substring, binary-data

I have two integers, lets call them `haystack` and `needle`. I need to check that, if the binary representation of `needle` occurred in `haystack` [and **OPTIONALLY** find the position of the first occurrence]

### Example

```py
haystack = 0b10101111010110010101010101110
needle = 0b1011001 # occurred in position 13
needle = 0b111011 # not occurred
```

I am looking for the least possible time complexity, I cannot write a code with time complexity better than `O(h)`, where `h` is the number of bits in the haystack. You can see my code below.

I need to check occurrence of a predefined `needle` (which never changes and it's an **odd** number), in billions of random `haystack` integers (So we cannot preprocess `haystack` to optimize speed)

As finding position is optional, if you can write a code with better time complexity to just return a Boolean that indicate occurrence, it's perfect too. Because in billions of check I know that it's not occurred and when it occurred I can use the following code to find the position.

A good probabilistic algorithm with False Positive results is fine too.

```py
def find_needle_in_haystack(haystack, needle):
    n = needle.bit_length()  # calculate the number of bits in needle
    mask = (1 << n) - 1  # create a mask with n bits
    i = 0
    while haystack != 0:
        x = haystack & mask  # bitwise AND with mask to get first n bits
        if x == needle:
            return i
        i += 1
        haystack >>= 1  # shift haystack to the right by 1 bit
    return -1  # needle not found in haystack
```

Comment: What's the maximum number of bits in the haystack? And the max for the needle?

Comment: For needle it's predefined, we are free to choose any bits, let say `64` or anything else. haystack is very very large and indeterminate. consider million of bits. I can make haystack smaller if you have a idea

Comment: if it helps, `haystack` is actually a stream of random bits. it's length is billions of bits. as it doesn't fit in ram, I chucked it to million of bits and in my question `haystack` is chunk of it (I can chunk it to smaller number of bits  too but as I need to generate the next bits of `haystack` it will be faster if I choose large number of bits)
In a `while True` loop, when I generate the `haystack` stream, I need to stop the loop by finding occurrence of `needle` and it happens after billions of loops

Comment: Ok, that clears things up a lot. Nothing comes to mind immediately, but I'll think about it.

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of `find` in the `bitstring` module? https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/

Comment: So what about needle length? Is it always/usually short?

Comment: @MBo I can generate needle as big as I want, it can be any desired length

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If needle length is NL, you can make NL masks of shifted needles (`0b1011001, 0b10110010, 0b101100100...`) and check them in parallel

Comment: @MBo Yes, I thought of that, but how? consider `1011001` as needle, it has 7 bits, if we multiply it by `(1<<7)+1` it produce two repeats of needle with is `10110011011001` lets call it  `two_needle`, Generally we can produce `n_needle` but for simplicity consider `two_needle` for now, How to check them in parallel?

Comment: if I do `haystack ^ (n_needle << y)` It can generate sequence of `0s` if I choose the right `y` (numbers of shift, 0<=y<7). in my example haystack if we choose `y=6` the result is `10101111010110010101010101110 ^ 10110011011001000000` which is `10101111000000001110011101110` and we have seven 0s on the occurrence position, how to detect it?! how to choose right `y`?

Comment: @DanNagle I have read it, it's based on regex for my use case because bytealigned 
 is False https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring/blob/main/bitstring.py#L2657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Python is a poor choice of language for this.  One way or another you will do a lot of bit twiddling.  Python is a high level language with slow abstraction layers for programmer convenience.  That adds a lot of overhead onto any simple looking bit twiddle.

That said, I would recommend using a pre-computed lookup table for this.  The idea is as follows.  We need an array of, by number of matched bits, by next byte, the number of currently matched bits.  This can be stored in an array of length `bits * 256`.  With the value at position `256*a + b` being a number from telling you that if you'd previously matched `a` bits and `b` is the next byte, how many bits you've NOW matched.

And now your logic looks something like this (ignoring casting):

```
matched = 0
for b in bytes:
    matched = lookup[256*matched + int(b)]
    if matched == length_of_needle:
        return True
return False
```

---

Here is some sample code demonstrating the idea.  Note that I 0-padded the end of the bits to wind up with an even number of bytes.

```
# Assuming that needle is an array of bits.
def needle_to_lookup (needle):
    ord2bits = []
    for j in range(256):
        bits = []
        k = j
        for _ in range(8):
            bits.append(k % 2)
            k = k // 2
        ord2bits.append(tuple(reversed(bits)))

    lookup = []
    for i in range(len(needle) + 1):
        for bits in ord2bits:
            # Do we successfully keep matching?
            matched = i
            for j in range(8):
                if i + j == len(needle):
                    matched = i+j
                    break
                elif needle[i+j] == bits[j]:
                    matched = i+j
                else:
                    matched = 0
                    break
            if 0 == matched: # Failed to extend for a byte.
                for j in range(8):
                    for k in range(8 - j):
                        if k == len(needle):
                            matched = k
                            break
                        elif needle[k] == bits[j+k]:
                            matched = k+1
                        else:
                            matched = 0
                            break
                    if 0 < matched:
                        break
            lookup.append(matched)
    return lookup

def find_needle(needle, byte_list):
    lookup = needle_to_lookup(needle)
    matched = 0
    for byte in byte_list:
        matched = lookup[256*matched + byte]
        if matched == len(needle):
            return True
    return False
            

print(find_needle([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], bytes([175, 89, 85, 184])))
print(find_needle([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], bytes([175, 89, 85, 184])))
```

Comment: I didn't get your solution at all! What do you mean of `bits`, `a` and `b`?! What is the time complexity of your solution?

Comment: Consider that `haystack` is a **RANDOM** integer

Comment: @WebMaster By `bits` I mean `how many bits have you matched at this point`.  And you said that we could look at `haystack` as a stream of random bits, which can in turn be seen as a stream of random bytes.  Processing bytes is faster than processing bits because one CPU operation does 8 bits. The time complexity is `O(number of bytes)` which is optimal but with a good constant.

Comment: I think, I cannot treat it as **Byte**, If I thread `needle=0b1011001` as byte it is `0b01011001` because I need to have 8 bits. in this case my needle is not occurred in my haystack, which is incorrect. Also `O(number of bytes)` is something like `O(number of bits/8)` in this case with is not a big difference for me

Comment: No, don't treat the needle as a byte, treat the **haystack** as bytes.

Comment: I added an implementation showing exactly what I mean.  If you have a binary file, you can open it in mode `rb` to read it directly as a stream of bytes that can be passed to this function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have read your code multiple time. I cannot understand how it works! Can you please tell me 1-Why we have `256`? 2-Can we check multiple bytes at the same time, instead of treating haystack as byte, treat it as n-bytes 3-Has this lookup algorithm a name? Can you refer me a resource, I am interested to learn more about it

Comment: The reason why 256 is that 1 byte has 8 bits can represent any number from 0 to 255. CPUs have built-in instructions to operate on bytes very quickly. You can in principle do this with any number of bytes, but then the lookup table gets big. https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832 shows why you want the table to fit in an L1 cache, which is often 32k. The idea of the table is vaguely inspired by the Boyer–Moore algorithm. Which, with a lot of complexity could be adapted to speed this up even more for long needles.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a bit of outside the box solution - you can try to convert the binary representation to a string and then use the `str.find` method.
For example:

```py
In [7]: haystack = 10101111010110010101010101110

In [8]: needle = 1011001

In [9]: str_haystack = str(haystack)

In [10]: str_needle = str(needle)

In [11]: str_haystack.find(str_needle)
Out[11]: 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The time complexity of your solution is not better than mine. Actually my own solution is much faster and use less memory.  Converting an int to string use more memory and it takes `O(N)` time

Comment: your'e probably right, if the main purpose is memory and time optimization your solution will be better.
I wanted to share something easy and readable, which might be good enough